# Rhodes without erb

Tags: ruby, rhodes

I quit using erb a couple of years ago in favor of haml. For me a great time saver. Now I am about to start work on my first Rhodes app and wondering what templating engines besides erb work well Rhodes.

If erb is it, well, if I must I must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, only erb is supported..